# Transform `SELECT` .. `UNION ALL` `SELECT` .. into something more efficient?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all

I have following query, which works, but I guess it can it be improved to something more efficient, how to do it?

1. all the values are from 1 table
2. 1st part of the result are always 2 rows having some a relation forming 1 row with all the fields set
3. 2nd part of the result are rows with some condition not participating in the first part which already have the right fields

```
    SELECT
      row1.field1 AS field1,
      row1.field2 AS field2,
      row2.field3 AS field3,
    FROM
      table1 row1
    JOIN
      table1 row2
    ON
      row1.field = row2.field_reference
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
    FROM
      table1
    WHERE
      condition = 'I_am_sure_those_rows_are_not_returned_in_the_SELECT_above'
```

Comment: Just some notes, row1 and row2 are very confusing _table_ aliases. Also, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: I guess you can do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: @jarlh Tables have both columns and fields.

Comment: In some way, the SQL data type date has a year field, a month field and a day field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited after reading @jarlh comment on another answer - should be COALESCE.

How about this - using a LEFT JOIN plus an OR statement in WHERE clause should return all those in row2 table AND all those meeting whatever your other condition is.

```
SELECT
row1.field1 AS field1,
row1.field2 AS field2,
coalesce(row2.field3, row1.field3) as field3
FROM table1 row1
LEFT JOIN table1 row2 ON row1.field = row2.field_reference

WHERE 
row2.field_reference is not null
OR condition = 'I_am_sure_those_rows_are_not_returned_in_the_SELECT_above'
```

Comment: Thanks! I always had and have a problem thinking in SQL. It's kind of unstructured for me, I hope I get better in that over time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT row1.field1 AS field1, row1.field2 AS field2, 
       coalesce(row2.field3, row1.field3) AS field3,
FROM table1 row1 LEFT JOIN
     table1 row2
     ON row1.field = row2.field_reference;
```

This returns *all* rows from `table1` along with matching columns from `table2` if they exist.

Comment: Seems like OP wants `coalesce(row2.field3, row1.field3) as field3`.

Comment: this answer is incomplete as it does not use the extra condition.

Comment: @Conffusion . . . The implication is that the extra condition is used to identify the rows that do not match the first `join`.